# Android: How to mathematically manipulate a resource value?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have a resource value `@dimen/height` that needs to be 'inverted' (like multiplied by -1), as in:

```
<item name="android:layout_height" >@dimen/height</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginTop" >@dimen/height * -1</item>
```

How do i do this without needing a run time script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new resource with the manipulated value and use it.
You seem to be dealing in xml.
If you assign values programatically at runtime, you can perform mathematical operations on values.

Comment: Haha, I guess i have to live with it. :3 Tnx.

Comment: Yeah, we simply can't do it in XML.